# Question on probability of random selection of point on a plane.

Tags: probability

Let us consider a plane.As we know, a plane has infinite no. of points. Let us say we have a point P. Then the probability of choosing P from the plane would be 1-over-infinity, which is 0. But what if P is actually chosen? This means that P has a chance of being selected.

I would like to know if I am conceptually wrong, or if this is a valid question.

Thanks,

Sandeep.

Comment: _Zero probability_ is not the same as _impossible_.

Comment: You are adding infinitely many infinitesimally small probabilities, whose sum is finite and equals 1.

Comment: @StackTD: What if P is chosen, despite the zero probability?

Comment: Nothing 'happens'... ;-). What do you mean exactly; or what do you expect? You could also check [Zero probability and impossibility](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility) and [Does 0% chance mean impossible?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882784/does-0-chance-mean-impossible)

Comment: @Sandeep that is what StackTD is saying. Something can have probability zero but still be chosen because 0 probability does not imply impossibility. If it helps you can think of the point having infinitesimally small probability.

Comment: In reality, you can't pick/describe a specific point due to measurement error, so every "point" has a positive probability in fact.